# Laravel Getting Child table values with multiple Parent values

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I need your help to find a solution in laravel 5. So let me explain my problem I have 4 tables lets suppose these are users, table1, table2, table3.

users and table1 have many to many relationship.
then table1 and table2 have many to many relationship.
and then table2 and table3 have many to many relationship.

Now on table3 controller i want to get all values with respect to a user. for example

```
   $table1 = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->table1()->get()->lists('id');
   $table2 = table1::whereIn('id',$table1)->table2()->get()->list('id');
   $table3 = table2::whereIn('id',$table2)->table3()->get();
```

On table2 data i am  getting the error of badmethodexception. I have googled and read the documentation but unable to get anywhere.

Can anyone help me how can i get the data please?

I have pivot table of table1_user, table1_table2 and table2_table3.

In user model i have function

```
public function table1(){
   $this->blongstomany('App\table1');
}
```

In Table1 Model i have function

```
public function table2(){
   $this->belongstomany('App\table2');
}
```

In Table2 Model i have function

```
public function table3(){
   $this->belongstomany('App\table3');
}
```

I hope now it make sense.

Comment: Can you post the relations also?

Comment: @JilsonThomas I have amended the question. Can you please help?